# Tails/Tor Browser not connecting to the internet

Tags: security, tails

I have been using Tails successfully for a little while now. However, once I removed the HDD from my computer and then tried using Tails, the Tor Browser would not connect to the internet. THe onion router had the big X through it. Tails stated that it was trying to set the clock because it would not work properly without the correct time and day. But it already had set the clock correctly. If I had to guess, I would say that not having the hard drive in the computer is affecting the ability of Tailsto connect to the internet.

I am writing this message in Tails/Tor Browser *after* putting the hard drive back in - no problems here.

I need to keep the HDD out of my computer when using Tails, like now. What do I need to do to eliminate this problem. I am a beginner when it comes to Linux. 
Thank you!!

Comment: I have had similar connection problems in the past, particularly when the system time on my computer has, for some unknown reason, become corrupted and differed substantially from the actual local time. Correcting the system time (by going into the BIOS when the computer boots) and then rebooting Tails has usually corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "modifiable"/writable partition to your Tails USB stick. The problem is that Tails does behave strange sometimes if it does not have such a partition *on a pendrive*.